# Can't save model after using Lambda layer in Keras

Tags: python, keras

My Keras verison is 2.0.8. I added this code snippet:

```
        units = 32
        hidden_with_time_axis = Lambda(lambda x: K.expand_dims(x,1))(layer)
        W1 = Dense(units)(kb_embedding)
        W2 = Dense(units)(hidden_with_time_axis)
        out = Add()([W1,W2])
        score = Lambda(lambda x: K.tanh(x))(out)
        out2 = Dense(1)(score)
        attention_weights = Lambda(lambda x: K.softmax(x))(out2)
        context = Lambda(lambda x: x * kb_embedding)(attention_weights)
        context_vector = Lambda(lambda x: K.sum(context,axis=1))(context)

        layer = merge([layer,context_vector], mode='concat')
        # Classification layers
        denseSize = self.getParameter("dense", self.styles, 400, parameters, 1)

        if denseSize > 0:
            layer = Dense(denseSize, activation='relu')(layer) #layer = Dense(800, activation='relu')(layer)
        assert self.cmode in ("binary", "multiclass", "multilabel")
        if self.cmode in ("binary", "multilabel"):
            layer = Dense(dimLabels, activation='sigmoid')(layer)
        else:
            layer = Dense(dimLabels, activation='softmax')(layer)
        if self.tag == 'entity-' or self.tag =='edge-':
            feature_embedding = sum([self.embeddings[x].inputLayers for x in embNames], [])
            feature_embedding.append(kb_embedding)
            kerasModel = Model(feature_embedding,layer)
```

Then the error ocurred:

```
TypeError: can't pickle NotImplementedType objects
```

Apparently it is because Keras model can't be serialization if you didn't use Lambda layer properly, but I don't know how to modify my code to make it work.

Comment: What is `kb_embedding`? One error is in the last line: replace `context` with `x` in `lambda` function.

Comment: yes, thanks for reminding me, I've fixed it, but the same error still exists.

Comment: And what is `kb_embedding`? Your code does not seem complete to me, i.e. there is a portion we cannot see and therefor have no idea what is happening there.

Comment: `kb_embedding` is a Keras `Input` layer with a 3d shape

Comment: `kb_embedding = Input(shape=(11,KBImporter.BIO_W2V_DIMENSION), name = 'KB')`

Comment: Have you tried upgrading your Keras to the latest version and see if the error is resolved?

Comment: Try using Concatenate instead of merge

Comment: I upgraded the tensorflow and keras to the latest version, then the error occurred at the same line as : `TypeError: pybind11_object.__new__(tensorflow.python._tf_stack.StackSummary) is not safe, use object.__new__()
`

Comment: I tried, `Concatenate` doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

While working with tensorflow.keras.layers.Lambda, it is best to use:

1. **Save weights: model.save_weights()**
2. **Load weights: model.load_weights()**